# Column to a single row with each data in parenthesis

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I need help to do the following conversion.

I want same thing like this: 
[image]
Column `7151 7152 7153 7154` To a single row --> `(7151)|(7152)|(7153)|(7154)`

Comment: What version of excel are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2016 version.

Comment: Do you have the `TEXTJOIN` function in your version of Excel?  If you do, then `="(" & TEXTJOIN(")|(",TRUE,A1:A4) & ")"`

Answer (score 1):

```
="("&A1&")|("&A2&")|("&A3&")|("&A4&")"
```

If the used range in column A contains a lot of data (or sometimes change), you should rather use the vba code to generate result.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a VBA code custom function.

In your excel sheet press ALT+F11 to open VBA Editor. From File Menu insert a module and double click on the module name in left pane (if needed) to open the source code editor.  Paste the following code into it.

```
 Function TXTJOIN(argument1 As Range)      'Accept input range

   rowcounter = argument1.Rows.Count
   If rowcounter > 255 Then
        TXTJOIN = CVErr(xlErrValue)  'If row counter > 255 return #VALUE! Error
        Exit Function
   End If
   colcounter = argument1.Columns.Count ' Check the number of columns in the input range

   If colcounter = 1 Then  'Process if it's a single column range

        For Each element In argument1
            result = result & "(" & element & ")" & "|"
        Next element

        TXTJOIN = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
   Else

        TXTJOIN = CVErr(xlErrValue)  'If it's a multicolumn range, return #VALUE! Error
   End If


End Function
```

Save the code and exit. If you are using Office 2007 and above you would need to save the Excel workbook as .xlsm Macro enabled excel workbook.

This way we have created a custom function called TXTJOIN.

Use this in your sheet now as shown in below picture.

[image]

Note that this custom function is simplified to work only on single column. Passing a multi column range to it shall return #VALUE! Error. This will work only in this workbook  as the code exists in this workbook. Moreover to avoid A:A being passed to it, it restricts to maximum 255 cells to concatenate.